# Css reference failing after deployment

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I have a CSS reference, defined as...

```
 td.details-control {
    background: url('../../Content/plugins/dataTables/details_open.png') 
          no-repeat center center;
          cursor: pointer;
}
```

The actual path, locally, to the png, is...

```
http://localhost:59328/Content/plugins/dataTables/details_open.png
```

The problem is, when I deploy it to the production server the path is now....

```
http://test.myproductionserver.com/PrimaryDomain/Content/plugins/dataTables/details_open.png
```

So, as you can see "/PrimaryDomain/" is causing me issues with the png reference. How can I fix this?

I tried making the png path to this, but it doesn't work...

```
'~/Content/plugins/dataTables/details_open.png'
```

Comment: is your css file in the same folder

Comment: Looking at a library I use, the references in the CSS are relative to the CSS file, i.e. the CSS file is in content/css and has "background-image: url('Black/sprite.png');" and the image is found successfully in content/css/Black no matter where I deploy.

Comment: @Geeky no it isn't.

Comment: @TheDreadPirateStephen In my case the localhost has one less subdirectory "level" than production. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't writing the absolute path a solution?

```
background: url('/Content/plugins/dataTables/details_open.png')
```

This way you will get:

```
http://test.myproductionserver.com/Content/plugins/dataTables/details_open.png
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. This error: http://test.myproductionserver.com/Content/plugins/dataTables/details_open.png ... Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) .... it's missing "/PrimaryDomain/".